# Types of definitions

Tags: terminology, definition

My question is about terminology.

Consider the following two types of definitions of a circle:

1. A circle is the collection of all points at the same distance from a given point.
2. A circle is the result of projecting a 3D sphere on a 2D plane and taking its convex hull.

What do you call these two types of definitions? The difference between the types is that the second definition tries to define not what the object is but rather how it is generated. Perhaps "explicit/implicit definition" (for the first/second type)? "generative definition" (for the second type)?

By the way the question is not specific to this example, but on general terminology - so I can switch examples if this one is not adequate.

An alternative more abstract example (try not to get caught on the details):

1. An egg is a white (or brownish) object which has a hard shell and a soft interior with a high concentration of albumin.
2. An egg is whatever the chicken lays.

Comment: I don't see a fundamental difference between your 1 and 2. The first one can also be phrased as "the result of": it's the result of collecting all points that are at distance $r$ from the center.   A more fundamental distinction is between what something is, and how it behaves. For example, the definition of Lebesgue space describes its elements. The definition of a vector space describes what can we do with its elements, not what they are.

Comment: The second definition needs specificity in the description of the "projection" but taking it as it is, it defines a disk (or filled in circle) not just the circle.  The first definition is fine.

Comment: Ok I think I should maybe add a more abstract example, since my question is not about the specifics.

Comment: You're reading 'projecting' as some sort of action, but this is just a word. When it comes down to it, you're just saying a circle is a certain set (perhaps with different descriptions, but similar in its essence).

Comment: Hmm... perhaps this is not the right SE, since in math definitions are always "generative" to some extent?

Comment: @Bitwise Perhaps this isn't the right S.E. site, yes. But there are similar questions which could be fitted here, for instance if the goal of the question was impredicative vs predicative definitions. And these aren't necessarily 'generative' (I think).

Comment: @GitGud In real life, it seems to me that there is a difference between defining what an object is by describing the object itself and defining what an object is by describing how it is generated. I just don't know if this distinction makes sense in math.

Comment: Compare "A field is a field of reals if it's dedekind complete." to "A field is a field of reals if it's isomorphic as an ordered field to the following: [dedekind cuts construction]". I think this is close to what Bitwise is getting at, but the distinction doesn't hold mathematical significance, to my knowledge.